# async call to component.create() does not return

Tags: unit-testing, jasmine, aurelia

I'm trying to get a jasmine test to run in Karma for an Aurelia project that will require custom configuration of the startup configuration.
Here is the test

```
it("dreams to be a plugin", async () => {
        const component = StageComponent.withResources();
        component.configure = (aurelia) => {
            return aurelia.use.standardConfiguration();
        };
        await component.create(bootstrap);
        expect(true).toBeTruthy();
    });
```

Unfortunately the test fails, because the call to `component.create()` does not return, and jasmine times out and fails the test.

[Here](https://github.com/ordinaryorange/aurelia-karma-test-bones) is a repo that shows the issue.

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 0):

Does `component.create()` return a `Promise`? `async`/`await` should work if it's a `Promise`.

```js
it("should support async/await tests", async () => {
  let flag = false;
  flag = await asyncSetFlagToTrue();
  expect(flag).toBeTruthy();
});

function asyncSetFlagToTrue() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(true);
    }, 1000);
  });
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasmine/3.0.0/jasmine.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasmine/3.0.0/jasmine.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasmine/3.0.0/jasmine-html.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasmine/3.0.0/boot.min.js"></script>
```

**Update**

I cloned from GitHub and added two tests to `component-tester.spec.ts`. Both passed.

```
it('should test async call using done', (done) => {
  component.configure = (aurelia) => {
    return aurelia.use.standardConfiguration();
  };
  component.create(bootstrap).then(() => done());
  expect(true).toBeTruthy();
});

it('should test async call using async/await', async () => {
  component.configure = (aurelia) => {
    return aurelia.use.standardConfiguration();
  };
  await component.create(bootstrap);
  expect(true).toBeTruthy();
});
```

Comment: Here is the source in TypeScript. (https://github.com/aurelia/testing/blob/master/src/component-tester.ts) The create method signature returns a `Promise<any>`. I've tried widening out the Jasmine timeout, but that did not work either. At this stage I'm suspecting a fault in the aurelia-testing lib

Comment: aargh, I just copied your code in and ran it, but the async tests fail my end. Where are you defining `component` ?

Comment: I just used the one already in the test specs file. It's shared at the top of `component-tester.specs.ts`. Line 5 `let component: ComponentTester;`

Comment: sorry still confused my end. Did you clone my repo ? It does not have a `component-tester.specs.ts` ? Did you add that file ? That's why I'm lost when you say "I just used the one already in the test specs file."

Comment: You provided a link to the source code for `component-tester.ts`, so I just backed up from that to the top of the repo and cloned from https://github.com/aurelia/testing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164937/discussion-between-ordinaryorange-and-joe-wilson).

Comment: Nope, but I have one of the Aurelia team looking into it.